# Does robots.txt stop Google from indexing my site or the files CodeIgniter uses?

Tags: codeigniter, seo

I have a site built in CodeIgniter and I am trying to utilize Google's webmaster tools which tell me to setup a robots.txt file. I want Google to index the whole site but not necessarily the files which make up the site. So I don't want good to look at the /system/ files or the /application/config/ files but I do want every page to be indexed. Should I list out each file for the Google not to index or tell it to index all or tell it to index nothing?
Thanks!

Comment: Google can only spider or index what physical web URL's exist. If you try to access `system` files CI won't allow it. Basically if it doesn't render HTML Google can't index it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google only see the pages/URLs your website makes available. So you don't block *files*, you block *pages*. So, your robots.txt should contain the URLs you don't want indexed. The files behind the scenes are irrelevant.